# Why the tabular column specifier C doesn't work?

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm using the tabular enviroment `\begin{tabular}` ... `\end{tabular}` inside of the beamer class `\begin{frame}` ... `\end{frame}` tags. 
In standard latex documents, i often use something like

```
\begin{tabular}{C{2.5cm} C{1cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm}}`
```

to predefine column widths. 
This seems not to work inside of beamer frames, i get the error:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.
```

Replacing 'C' with 'c' leads to:

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (2.5cm): `c' used.
```

Why does the interpreter complains about setting the width? 
Is there a universal solution to handle that issue in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to define the columntype `C`. I guess you want something like

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

Comment: @ Marco Daniel: this is exactly the problem, thanks for the quick reply and a practical solution (and for formatting my post)!